# Не перехватывается выброшенное исключение

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Вызываю метод, который при искл.чение перебрасывает его наверх, чтобы обработать во внешнем коде

```
    private async void FillCurrentWeather(string place)
    {          
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Current));
        string xml = await GetWeather(CurrentWeatherUrl,place,7);
        if (xml != null)
        {
            try
            {
                TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
                Current forecast = (Current)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                PlaceName.Content = forecast.City.Name + "," + forecast.City.Country;
                CurrentWeather.Update(forecast);
                reader.Dispose();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
            }
        }
    }
```

Внешний код

```
try
{
    FillCurrentWeather(place);
    FillDayWeather(place);
    FillWeekWeather(place);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при обработке данных внешнего сервиса\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

Но исключение не обрабатываеися и выскакивает в отладчике. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: А какое исключение в откладчике? Скопируйте его сюда, пожалуйста.

Comment: То, которое пытаюсь перехватить. InvalidOperationException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: В документе XML (1, 1) присутствует ошибка.

Comment: Хм... А можете показать полностью код метода, который выбрасывает исключение?

Comment: _"выскакивает в отладчике"_ - при отладке в VS что ли? Тогда посмотреть какие Exception Settings выставлены. _Debug-->Windows-->Exception Settings_ (`Ctrl+Alt+E`).

Comment: рекомендация: `throw;` вместо `throw new Inva...;`

Comment: @Rostislav 
Изменил вопрос

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Во время выполнения под отладчиком выпадают все исключения, отмеченные в списке Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>). Это нормально. Если вы продолжите выполнение программы (<kbd>F5</kbd>), то дальше отработают ваши `catch` блоки.

**UPD**

С добавление полного кода стала понятна настоящая причина, к которой предыдущий абзац не имеет никакого отношения. Проблема в этом:

```
async void FillCurrentWeather
```

Для полного понимания того, как работает async/await, отсылаю к [видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA). Здесь же вкратце опишу, что происходит при выполнении программы. Итак:

1. В блоке `try` внешнего кода вызывается метод `FillCurrentWeather(place);`.
2. Выполнение метода `FillCurrentWeather` доходит до этой строки и покидает его*:

   ```
   string xml = await GetWeather(CurrentWeatherUrl,place,7);
   ```
3. В блоке `try` внешнего кода отрабатывают все остальные методы.
4. Метод `GetWeather` завершает выполнение, продолжается выполнение метода `FillCurrentWeather`, вываливается исключение. НО! Блок `try/catch` во внешнем коде уже завершился, он не может поймать это исключение! Поэтому исключение вываливается на самом верхнем уровне как необработанное (`UnhandledTaskException`).

`async void` опасны именно по этим причинам:

- мы не знаем, когда они на самом деле завершаются
- соответственно мы не может адекватно реагировать на исключения в таких методах

`async void` сигнатуру можно использовать только для событий и методов, имеющих событийную семантику, плюс не забывать целиком оборачивать все тело таких методов в `try/catch`, поскольку если возникнет исключение, вы либо получите необработанное исключение (если возникло в UI потоке), либо, в случае если оно возникло в потоке пула, вы об этом или не узнаете, или это исключение убьет процесс (в случае с .NET 4.0 будет именно так).

Какие у вас варианты решения? В данном случае -- только один: изменить сигнатуру метода на `async Task` и ожидать завершения этого метода во внешнем коде.

И еще маленький совет: в вашем случае блок `try/catch` в методе `FillCurrentWeather` вообще не нужен, поэтому что он по сути ничего не делает. Просто уберите его. (А впредь, если хотите пробрасывать исключения, оборачивая их в другие, всегда включайте исключение целиком, а не его `InnerException`, которого может и не быть: `throw new Exception("This is new exception", e)`).

---

*на самом деле это упрощение, и выполнение продолжится вглубь до того момента, когда вызов уйдет к IO-устройству. Важно лишь, что программа не дожидается завершения этого метода.

**UPD2**

Чтобы не терять параллелизацию получения данных о погоде, которая невольно достигалась при использовании `async void` методов, нужно использовать `Task.WhenAll`:

```
try
{
    var currentTask = FillCurrentWeather(place);
    var dayTask = FillDayWeather(place);
    var weekTask = FillWeekWeather(place);
    await Task.WhenAll(currentTask, dayTask, weekTask);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при обработке данных внешнего сервиса\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделал, как вы сказали. Теперь жду завершения каждого метода с помощью await. Такой вопрос, теперь асинхронность ведь полностью пропадает? В данном случае это не критично, но все таки такой вариант не радует.

Comment: @Владимир обновил ответ.